# How to obtain R1 from MAX31740ATA+T equation?

Tags: pwm, voltage-divider

How to obtain R1 from MAX31740ATA+T equation ?

The equation:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose the Dmin that is appropriate for your system. After that, it's just algebra.

Rearranging the equation gives R1 = ((200*R2)/Dmin) - R2.

The datasheet doesn't give any information on input leakage current for the Dmin pin & wesbite doesn't have reference designs, so order of magnitude for the resistors is hard to know. 10's of K or 100's of K ranges might be acceptable. Best answer is to contact a Maxim FAE.